# How to adjust the size of edges when we have large number of items in tikz-tree?

Tags: tikz-trees

I am working on a hierarchy diagram which has large number of items on its leaves due to which my diagram goes out of page and eventually i am unable to see right half of tree following is the code I used which is partial half of the items are still not present in it if I add them just like `text summarization` they hide.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\begin{document}   
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south)
        -- +(0,-8pt)
        -| (\tikzchildnode)}},
blank/.style={draw=none}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix
{

\node{\Tree 
    [.{Text Summarization} 
    [.{Extractive Summarization} 
    [.{Similarity}
    Topic Cluster  ] 
    [.{Classification} 
    test2 test1 ]
    [.{Feature Selection}
    test1 test2 test3 ] 
    [.{Feature Extraction}
    test2 test3 ] 
    ]
    [.{Abstractive Summarization} ] ]

    };\\
 };           
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want a solution with the help of which I can somehow adjust the length of edges (some small and some large) in such a way that I can see full hierarchy without going out of the page.

Comment: Is `forest` an option? It creates more compact trees.

Comment: `mitthesis` is not a standard class. Can we use something else? If not, where can we get it? (E.g. if it sets some non-standard page layout which is why your tree won't fit, we might need it. Right now, I'm assuming that's not the case.)

Comment: @cfr yes forest is an option but it too grows out of page when nodes increase, if you can demonstrate with forest it is acceptable, and you can follow standard page layout and ignore `mitthesis`

Comment: You could also use a `schemata` rather than a tree?

Comment: You can reduce size of node font with `every tree node/.style={font=\scriptsize}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forest` specialises in creating compact trees. Obviously, if you add *enough* to the tree, it will grow too large. However, the tree in your MWE fits without any special effort into the width of a standard letter sized page. (I'm guessing from the `mitthesis` that you are using US sized paper.)

Here's the `forest` version:

[image: tree on letter paper]

This fits within the page width. (No overly full box warnings!)

For more stuff, you may need to use multi-line nodes. If so, `align=center` enables you to break the lines at will, or `text width=<some width>` enables auto-breaking.

The space to the right of this tree is within the page boundary:

[image: more compact again]

For even greater space savings, you can, for example, use `tier=<something>` to manage vertical alignments:

[image: tier alignment]

Here's a comparison with a frame for the page to show layout:

[image: comparison]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  }
  [Text Summarization
    [Extractive Summarization
      [Similarity
        [Topic]
        [Cluster]
      ]
      [Classification
        [test2]
        [test1]
      ]
      [Feature Selection
        [test1]
        [test2]
        [test3]
      ]
      [Feature Extraction
        [test2]
        [test3]
      ]
    ]
    [Abstractive Summarization]
  ]
\end{forest}
\bigskip

\noindent\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    align=center,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
  [Text Summarization
    [Extractive\\Summarization
      [Similarity
        [Topic]
        [Cluster]
      ]
      [Classification
        [test2]
        [test1]
      ]
      [Feature\\Selection
        [test1]
        [test2]
        [test3]
      ]
      [Feature\\Extraction
        [test2]
        [test3]
      ]
    ]
    [Abstractive\\Summarization]
  ]
\end{forest}
\bigskip

\noindent\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    align=center,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [\forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
  }
  [Text Summarization
    [Extractive\\Summarization
      [Similarity
        [Topic]
        [Cluster]
      ]
      [Classification
        [test2]
        [test1, tier=other]
      ]
      [Feature\\Selection, tier=other
        [test1]
        [test2]
        [test3]
      ]
      [Feature\\Extraction
        [test2]
        [test3]
      ]
    ]
    [Abstractive\\Summarization]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for presenting variations for hierarchy creation, it helped me to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This setup:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,showframe}
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,
grow=right, level 1/.style={sibling distance=2em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1em}, level distance=3.2cm,text width=2.2cm]
\matrix
{\node{\Tree 
    [.{Text Summarization}
    [.{Extractive\\ Summarization}
    [.{Similarity}
    Topic Cluster  ] 
    [.{Classification} 
    test2 test1 ]
    [.{Feature\\ Selection}
    test1 test2 test3 ] 
    [.{Feature\\ Extraction}
    test2 test3 ]]
    [.{Abstractive\\ Summarization} ]]
    };\\
 };           
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Or this one:

[image]

With a different setting:

```
\tikzset{font=\small,
grow=right,text width=2.2cm,
edge from parent/.style=
{draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east)
        -- +(8pt,0)
        |- (\tikzchildnode)}},
blank/.style={draw=none}}
```